# clojure - is-prime? prime numbers

Tags: clojure

function named is-prime? which takes an input n and returns true if n is
prime, and false otherwise. This function should check to see if n is 1 or 2 and
respond accordingly; if not, it should call your no-divisors?.

```
(defn divides? [div n] (zero? (mod n div)))

 (defn no-divisors? [n]
  (->> (range 2 n)
   (filter #(divides? % n))
   empty?))
```

problem code below

```
(defn is-prime? [n]
(and (> n 1) (not-any? (filter #(no-divisors? % n)) (range 2 n))))

/// current output///
(is-prime? 1)
 => false
(is-prime? 2)
 => true
(is-prime? 3)
 => false
(is-prime? 4)
 => false
(is-prime? 101)
 => false
/// current output///

/// required output ///
(is-prime? 1)
 => false
 (is-prime? 2)
 => true
 (is-prime? 3)
 => true
 (is-prime? 4)
 => false
 (is-prime? 101)
 => true
 /// required output ///
```

help would be appreciated

Comment: What debugging have you done? Where have you narrowed the problem down to? Have you checked any of the data that lead up to the incorrect result? And please show a [mcve] that includes all relevant code, like `divides?`.

Comment: hi, i am new to clojure and working on a small project to get a better understanding. code related to divides? is  "(defn divides? [div n]
  (zero? (mod n div)))"

Comment: Except for the case where n is 1, `no-divisors?` is already a test for whether or not n is prime, no?

Comment: no-divisors? which takes input n. The function returns true if none of the numbers between 2 and √ divide n, and false
otherwise, whereas is-prime? should take an input n and returns true if n is prime, and false otherwise, This function should check to see if n is 1 or 2 and respond accordingly; if not, it should call your no-divisors? function.

Answer (score 3):

The `no-divisors?` is redundant.

```
(letfn [(divides? [m n] (zero? (rem m n)))
        (prime? [n] (and (< 1 n) (not-any? #(divides? n %) (range 2 n))))]

    (prn (for [i (range 100)
                  :when (prime? i)] i)))
```

Comment: hi am using repl. i dont know how this code relates to mine

Comment: @llllollll It's a correct implementation of what you're trying to implement.

Comment: this code doesnt give me the required output that i require, the output above is what i require. i have tried this code but doesnt work, any more ideas will be welcome thanks